# Combining Multiple JSON reads from an API in a single JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull data from an API using Python and i am having trouble appending multiple json responses in a single JSON file. Essentially i want all json respnses from an API to be stored in one JSON file but i am having trouble with that. Appending a JSON to a list is not working either. The Idea is to save the final output in a JSON file
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
account_number=['sds','sdadf','rewer']
data_list=[]

for i in account_number:
    data = {"accountNumber" : i }
    pull= requests.post(url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user.strip(),password), json=data, headers=headers)
    output=json.loads(pull.content)
    data_list.append(output)
```

Comment: After the `for` you've got a list and could just `json.dump` it to a file. Am i missing something?

Comment: @tdelaney If i do that i get the following error :

---    
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
---

Below is what i am trying to do outside of for loop:

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data_list, outfile)

Comment: This is the `requests` module? Try letting it decode the response for you. `output=pull.json()`. If that doesn't work, post whtever `output` is so we can see what you've got.

Comment: Could you show what does the `pull.content` look like? Sounds like it has characters that can't be in a JSON document.